# PWA localhost network failure in Chromium

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm currently working on integrating a Service-Worker in my application. But I have problems when I want to test it on my local machine.

The caching in the `install`-Event is failing. I searched for the error for two days but I don't have ideas anymore. When I deploy the site on e.g. netlify everything works fine.

That's what the network tab is giving me:

[image: network tab]

Developer console is printing: 
[image: developer console]

Browser: `Chromium Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build)`

I activated `#allow-insecure-localhost` in the chrome flags. Webpack is serving over `https://localhost:8081` (with a self-signed certificate). If I right click the failed network requests and click `Open in new tab` everything works fine. 
The weird thing is that the failing files are changing every time.

Code in my `index.jsx` (entry point for webpack):

```js
...
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('/serviceWorker.js', { scope: "/" })
    .then(e => {
      console.log('Service Worker Registered');
      console.log(e);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log("Service Worker fail");
      console.log(e);
    })
  });
}
...
```

Code in my `serviceWorker.js`

```js
let cacheName = 'test';
let cachedURLs = [
    "/",
    "/bundle.js",
    "/manifest.webmanifest",
    "/favicon.ico",
    "/favicon-256.png"
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
      caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
        console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
        return cache.addAll(cachedURLs);
      })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {    
  event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
      })
  );    
});
```

---

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments I added a `catch`-block to the `cache.addAll`:

```
return cache.addAll(cachedURLs).catch(err => console.log('error: ', err));
```

But unfortunately it isn't more verbose:

```
error:  TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

For completeness this is what Chromium is reporting for a failed request (in this case it is the `bundle.js`)

[image: detail of failed request]

Comment: Hi, could you add a `catch` block to your promise in the `fetch` `event-listener`: `.catch(err => console.log('error: ', err)));`
Maybe it'll be more expressive

Comment: I had similar setup, but not having the window.addEventListener('load', ... in index.jsx. Also take care all cachedURLs should exist.

Comment: @t3__rry Yep, but this doesn't change anything, because the `fetch`-listener is never fired when initial rendering the page. The error is thrown in the `install`-listener (when caching the files with `cache.addAll`).

@Niels: Every file/URL exists, as I already pointed out in my post. I can load them if I open the failed requests.

Comment: @Dirk ok, did you try adding a `catch` block to the `install` listener then?

Comment: @t3__rry Yep, I tried it, but it doesn't give more insights. I updated my post and added a screenshot of a failed requests. Does this help?

Comment: @Dirk not really,  I thought you'd have more insights... I've came across this thread if it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160929/progressive-web-app-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-failed-to-fetch

Comment: @t3__rry I already found this thread, but thank you anyway. But I tried it without the `fetch`-listener. Same result. I tried it in incognito mode (without Chromium Addons) -> same result. And the files are spelled correctly.
My guess was, that the error lays within the `webpack-dev-server`. But it doesn't seem so, I activated `verbose`mode of `express`. The failed requests doesn't even reach express. So my guess is that Chromium is failing...

Comment: @Dirk yes that's weird... and your implementation is right so I guess it's on Chromium's end as well